# How do I get the value of a classed object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, foreach

I need to hardcode a simple foreach function that console.logs out a list of objects with the same value for a specific property from an array.  but console.log keeps showing undefined.  I don't know what I did wrong here.  is the class defined that is causing a problem?  If i just have to work with classes, how do i solve this problem?

```
class Hive {
     constructor(apiary_name, hive_name, hive_number) {
     this.apiary_name = apiary_name;
     this.hive_name = hive_name;
     this.hive_number = hive_number;
}}

const Hive1_A1 = new Hive(A1, 'My First Hive in A1', 1111)
const Hive2_A1 = new Hive(A1, 'My Second Hive in A1', 2222)
const Hive3_A1 = new Hive(A1, 'My Third Hive in A1', 3333)
const Hive1_A2 = new Hive(A2, 'My First Hive in A2', 1111)
const Hive2_A2 = new Hive(A2, 'My Second Hive in A2', 2222)
const Hive3_A2 = new Hive(A2, 'My Third Hive in A2', 3333)

const Hives = [
    {Hive1_A1},{Hive2_A1},{Hive3_A1},{Hive1_A2},{Hive2_A2},{Hive3_A2},
]

function listHives(ApiaryName_Hive_1){
    var hives = Hives;
    hives.forEach((hive) => {
        if(hive.apiary_name === ApiaryName_Hive_1) {
            console.log(hive);
        } else {
            console.log('No hives in apiary A1 can be found')
        }
    });
}

listHives('A1')
```

by calling the function listHives('A1'), I am expecting in console.log to see just Hive_1_A1, Hive_2_A1, Hive_3_A1 listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
const Hives = [
    {Hive1_A1},{Hive2_A1},{Hive3_A1},{Hive1_A2},{Hive2_A2},{Hive3_A2},
]
```

You are using a JS shorthand that creates objects. This give you a list of objects like:

```
[{Hive1_A1: Hive1_A1}, {Hive2_A1: Hive2_A1} ...]
```

If you just want a list of Hives that you can iterate over, don't use the `{}` in the list definition, just make a plain array:

```
const Hives = [Hive1_A1, Hive2_A1, Hive3_A1...]
```

```js
class Hive {
    constructor(apiary_name, hive_name, hive_number) {
    this.apiary_name = apiary_name;
    this.hive_name = hive_name;
    this.hive_number = hive_number;
}}

const Hive1_A1 = new Hive("A1", 'My First Hive in A1', 1111)
const Hive2_A1 = new Hive("A1", 'My Second Hive in A1', 2222)
const Hive3_A1 = new Hive("A1", 'My Third Hive in A1', 3333)
const Hive1_A2 = new Hive("A2", 'My First Hive in A2', 1111)
const Hive2_A2 = new Hive("A2", 'My Second Hive in A2', 2222)
const Hive3_A2 = new Hive("A2", 'My Third Hive in A2', 3333)

const Hives = [Hive1_A1, Hive2_A1, Hive3_A1, Hive1_A2, Hive2_A2, Hive3_A2]

function listHives(ApiaryName_Hive_1){
   var hives = Hives;
   hives.forEach((hive) => {
       if(hive.apiary_name === ApiaryName_Hive_1) {
           console.log(hive);
       } else {
           console.log('No hives in apiary A1 can be found')
       }
   });
}

listHives('A1')
```